# Rails, Postgres: How to CREATE a pivot table and LEFT JOIN it to another table without hardcoding the columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, pivot-table

I am working in Rails and Postgres.
I have a table **Problems**, which has a few columns. I have another table **ExtraInfos**, which references Problems and has three columns: problem_id, info_type, info_value.

For example:

***Problems:***

| id | problem_type | problem_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | type_x | grp_a |
| 1 | type_y | grp_b |
| 2 | type_z | grp_c |

***ExtraInfos:***

| id | problem_id | info_type:String | info_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | info_1 | v1 |
| 1 | 0 | info_2 | v2 |
| 2 | 0 | info_3 | v3 |
| 3 | 1 | info_1 | v4 |
| 4 | 1 | info_3 | v5 |

As you can see, each problem has a variable number of extra information.

What is the best way to join both tables to create something that looks like:

| id | problem_type | problem_group | info_1 | info_2 | info_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | type_x | grp_a | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| 1 | type_y | grp_b | v4 |  | v5 |
| 2 | type_z | grp_c |  |  |  |

I used the ruby [pivot_table](https://github.com/edjames/pivot_table) gem, and I did manage to create the *view* that I wanted, by

```
@table = PivotTable::Grid.new do |g|
  g.source_data  = ExtraInfos.all.includes(:problem))
  g.column_name  = :info_type
  g.row_name     = :problem
  g.field_name   = :info_value
end
@table.build
```

and then iterating over it by

```
...
<% @table.columns.each do |col| %>
  <th><%= col.header %></th>
<% end %>
...
<% if @table.row_headers.include? problem %>
  <% table.rows[table.row_headers.index(problem)].data.each do |cell| %>
    <td><%= cell %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
...
```

but this is very clunky and doesn't leave me with good ways to, for instance, sort by these extra columns. As far as I know, the tables are simply a grid, an object, and can't `LEFT JOIN` with my `Problems.all` table, which would be the ideal solution.

I have tried looking up various pure SQL methods, but all seem to start with the assumption that these extra columns will be hard coded in, which is what I am trying to avoid. I came across [crosstab](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tablefunc.html), but I haven't managed to get it working as it should.

```
sql = "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;
    SELECT * FROM crosstab(
      'SELECT problem_id, info_type, info_value
      FROM pre_maslas
      ORDER BY 1,2'
    ) AS ct(problem_id bigint, info_type varchar(255), info_value varchar(255))"

@try = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

This gives me the result `{"problem_id"=>44, "info_type"=>"6", "info_value"=>"15"} {"problem_id"=>45, "info_type"=>"6", "info_value"=>"15"}` which is clearly not correct.

Another method seems to be creating a separate reference table containing a list of all possible infoTypes, which will then be referenced by the ExtraInfos table, making it easier to join the tables. However, I don't want the infoTypes coded in at all. I want the user to be able to give me *any* type and value strings, and my tables should be able to deal with this.

What is the best solution for accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord is built on top of the AST query assembler `Arel`.

You can use this assembler to build dynamic queries as needed basically if you can hand type it as a SQL query Arel can build it.

In this case the following will build your desired crosstab query based on the table structure provided in the post.

```
# Get all distinct info_types to build columns
cols = ExtraInfo.distinct.pluck(:info_type)
# extra_info Arel::Table
extra_infos_tbl = ExtraInfo.arel_table
# Arel::Table to use for querying 
tbl = Arel::Table.new('ct')

# SQL data type for the extra_infos.info_type column 
info_type_sql_type = ExtraInfo.columns.find {|c| c.name == 'info_type' }&.sql_type

# Part 1 of crosstab 
qry_txt = extra_infos_tbl.project( 
  extra_infos_tbl[:problem_id],
  extra_infos_tbl[:info_type],
  extra_infos_tbl[:info_value]
) 
# Part 2 of the crosstab  
cats =  extra_infos_tbl.project(extra_infos_tbl[:info_type]).distinct

# construct the ct portion of the crosstab query
ct = Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('ct',[
  Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Arel.sql('"problem_id"'), Arel.sql('bigint')),
  *cols.map {|name|  Arel::Nodes::TableAlias.new(Arel::Table.new(name), Arel.sql(info_type_sql_type))}
])

# build the crosstab(...) AS ct(...) statement
crosstab = Arel::Nodes::As.new(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('crosstab', [Arel.sql("'#{qry_txt.to_sql}'"),
    Arel.sql("'#{cats.to_sql}'")]),
  ct
)

# final query construction
q = tbl.project(tbl[Arel.star]).from(crosstab)
```

Using this `q.to_sql` will produce:

```
SELECT 
  ct.* 
FROM 
  crosstab('SELECT 
              extra_infos.problem_id, 
              extra_infos.info_type, 
              extra_infos.info_value 
            FROM 
              extra_infos', 
           'SELECT DISTINCT 
              extra_infos.info_type 
            FROM 
              extra_infos') AS ct(problem_id bigint, 
                                  info_1 varchar(255), 
                                  info_2 varchar(255), 
                                  info_3 varchar(255))
```

And results in

| problem_id | info_1 | info_2 | info_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| 1 | v4 |  | v5 |

We can join this to the problems table as

```
sub = Arel::Table.new('subq')
sub_q = Arel::Nodes::As.new(q,Arel.sql(sub.name)) 

out = Problem
  .joins(Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin.new(sub_q,            
            Arel::Nodes::On.new(Problem.arel_table[:id].eq(sub[:problem_id]))
  )).select(
     Problem.arel_table[Arel.star],
     *cols.map {|c| sub[c.intern]}
  )
```

This will return `Problem` objects where the `info_type` columns are virtual attributes. e.g. `out.first.info_1 #=> 'v1'`

**Note:** Personally I would break the parts down in a class to make the assembly clearer but the above will produce the desired outcome

Comment: This is working beautifully for me. I didn't exactly understand everything you did, because I didn't know Arel was even a thing, though I am going to look this up now. There's just one thing - when I try to  join this to the problems table, there's a strange column name mismatch:
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column subq.infoOne does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "problems".*, "subq"."infoOne", "subq"."infoTwo", ...
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "subq.infoone".

Comment: Looking further, I realized that q.to_sql is lowercasing all new column headers. I'm checking the query, otherwise, maybe I should just move to lowercase...

Comment: It turns out that Postgres will automatically lowercase any field that isn't quoted. So the _query_ is fine, but when it is executed, all column names turn lowercase.

Comment: After some trial and error, I fixed it by mapping the columns names given to the original pivoted table `cols.map { |p| '"' + p + '"'}`.

Comment: I also had to change the `Arel::Nodes::InnerJoin` to `Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin` but now it's working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You made the variable `cols = ExtraInfo.distinct.pluck(:info_type).sort`. I made another where I mapped the same variable (rubocop preferred `cols.map { |p| "\"#{p}\"" }`). I then used the quoted columns in the `ct = ...*quoted_cols` to make the pivoted table, but used the original when joining it with Problem `out = ...*cols`.

Comment: @HZaman okay fixed (in a slightly different manner).

Comment: And another thing: I'd been messing around with the SQL queries before so I'd run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;` already and had no problems. When I reset my db from scratch, it told me crosstab function did not exist, until I executed that query again. (ps. What did you change? I've been trying to figure it out, but I don't see it...)

Comment: @HZaman if you click on the hyperlink that says "edited XX mins ago" at the bottom of the post it will show you the changes. Also for the extension thing you can create a migration and use the the following `enable_extension 'tablefunc' unless extension_enabled?('tablefunc')` [See Here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/PostgreSQLAdapter#enable_extension-instance_method)

Comment: Thank you! (but you should be aware, that when I implemented your technique, there was a small column/value mismatch that fixed itself when I removed the `.sort` from `cols`.)

Answer (score 1):

In postgres, pivot table or crosstab are not relevant when the list of columns may vary in time, ie the list of values in column `info_type` may increase or decrease.

There is an other solution which consists in creating a `composite type` dynamically and then using the standard functions `jsonb_build_agg` and `jsonb_populate_record` :

Creating the composite type `column_list` dynamically :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE column_list() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  clist text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT info_type || ' text', ',')
    INTO clist
    FROM ExtraInfos ;
 
  EXECUTE 'DROP TYPE IF EXISTS column_list' ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE column_list AS (' || clist || ')' ;
END ; $$ ;
```

Then setting up the composite type `column_list` for the first time :

```
CALL column_list() ;
```

But this composite type must be updated after every change of column ExtraInfos. This can be achieved with a trigger function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION After_Insert_Update_Delete_ExtraInfos () RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
  CALL column_list() ;
  RETURN NULL ;
END ; $$ ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER After_Insert_Update_Delete_ExtraInfos AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF info_type OR DELETE ON ExtraInfos
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION After_Insert_Update_Delete_ExtraInfos () ;
```

The final query is :

```
SELECT p.id, p. problem_type, p.problem_group, (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: column_list, jsonb_object_agg(info_type, info_value))).*
  FROM Problems AS p
 INNER JOIN ExtraInfos AS ei
    ON ei.problem_id = p.id
 GROUP BY p.id, p. problem_type, p.problem_group
```

which gives the result :

| id | problem_type | problem_group | info_1 | info_2 | info_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | type_x | grp_a | v1 | v2 | v3 |
| 1 | type_y | grp_b | v4 | null | v5 |

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/e21CXUzq)

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know you could do functions in SQL. For some reason, though, LEFT JOIN isn't working on the tables, giving `ERROR:  field name must not be null.`