# Removing harcoded values from the sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

There's a `Country` table which has many countries in it. But my application is interested in only few countries referred to as `interestedCountries`. These can vary depending on the business logic. There's another table `VendorCheck` which has a vendor and the country combination. For each vendor we see what it's status in the `interestedCountry`. So the rows are vendordetails and the each `interestedCountry` is the column. It looks like this
[image: Vendor and Country]

If one of the `interestedCountry` is removed then the it's respective column in the `vendorCheck` table will also be removed.

In the application, there's a stored proc which utilizes the hardcoded values in the where condition to determine which of the columns to be considered.

```
 CASE a.countrycode
    WHEN 'IR' THEN d.ir not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')
    WHEN 'CU' THEN d.cu not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')
    WHEN 'SD' THEN d.sd not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')
    WHEN 'SY' THEN d.sy not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')
    WHEN 'VE' THEN d.ve not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')
    ELSE false
    END;
```

I want to make this to dynamic instead of hardcoded values like 'IR', 'CU' etc since If the user add in a new `interestedCountry` then there's a need to change the stored procedure.
Is there any way to achieve dynamyic functionality?

Comment: Hi! Could you add some sample data and the exact expected results?

Comment: Do you you want to have a loop instead of the spelled out `CASE`?

Comment: I want something like ```if a.countrycode then d.countrycode not in('Not Analyzed','Rejected')``` which means for a particular country it's respective column it's picked

Comment: you can do it in plpgsql with a dynamic command, something like `EXECUTE ' SELECT d.' || a.countrycode || E' NOT IN (\'Not Analysed\', \'Rejected\')`. But you still need to add/remove some columns in table VendorCheck when the interestCountries list is updated. An other full dynamic solution would be to create  a `View` based on a query similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74881468/8060017)

Answer (score 1):

JSON functions will do the job.

1. Convert each row in `vendorCheck` table into a JSON object
2. Use the given `interested_country` as the json path to extract value
3. Check if extracted value `not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED')`

For example, you have the following vendorCheck data:

```
vendor_number|vendor_name|vendor_type|ir          |cu      |sd          |sy          |ve          |
-------------+-----------+-----------+------------+--------+------------+------------+------------+
          123|ABC Vendor |XYZ        |Not Analyzed|Analyzed|Not Analyzed|Not Analyzed|Not Analyzed|
```

Given `interested_country='IR'`,

```sql
with params as (select 'ir' as interested_country)
select vendor_number, vendor_name, vendor_type, interested_country, 
       upper(json_extract_path_text(row_to_json(v.*), p.interested_country)) not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED') as is_interested
  from vendorCheck v, params p;
```

Result:

```
vendor_number|vendor_name|vendor_type|interested_country|is_interested|
-------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+
          123|ABC Vendor |XYZ        |ir                |false        |
```

Given `interested_country='CU'`,

```sql
with params as (select 'cu' as interested_country)
select vendor_number, vendor_name, vendor_type, interested_country, 
       upper(json_extract_path_text(row_to_json(v.*), p.interested_country)) not in ('NOT ANALYZED','REJECTED','LICENCE REQUIRED') as is_interested
  from vendorCheck v, params p;
```

Result:

```
vendor_number|vendor_name|vendor_type|interested_country|is_interested|
-------------+-----------+-----------+------------------+-------------+
          123|ABC Vendor |XYZ        |cu                |true         |
```

If more `country` columns added to `vendorCheck` table, the code works without any modification.